# I cannot figure out what formatting item is missing

Tags: java

I am missing a formatting item and for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is.  Class will not compile. Any help welcome!

```
package com.hcl.domain;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Grid {

    public char[][] layout = new char[10][10];

    for (char[] row : layout) {
    Arrays.fill(row, '-');
    }


}
```

Comment: You're missing a method.

Comment: You need to create a constructor and put your for loop logic in there to initialize the layout on a Grid object instantiation.

Comment: `foreach` loop cannot be executed in class scope. Create method constructor or another method to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines are executing parts in your class.

```
for (char[] row : layout) {
Arrays.fill(row, '-');
}
```

But as you have put it in just the class scope, it simply does not belong there because those cannot be executed there.

So you have to put this inside where you its being automatically executed or can where this can execute manually.

There are multiple choices for you like Constructor, Method Body etc.

So If you are willing to put them inside the Constructor, the code should be,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Grid
{

    public char[][] layout = new char[10][10];

    public Grid()
    {
        for ( char[] row : layout )
        {
            Arrays.fill( row, '-' );
        }

    }
}
```